# Strange behaviour when get current month in C#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, datetime-format

This is small code. But I couldn't find whats wrong with it. In my application I want to get the current month in long month format(ex:January). I used the following two lines of code.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string month = now.Month.ToString("MMMM",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

but its return "MMMM" for the values of month. Can anybody tell me whats wrong in this code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[now.Month](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.month.aspx) is the `int` representation the month e.g. 1 for January, that's why the `.ToString("MMMM")` works "strange".

What you need is to call the `.ToString()` directly on the `DateTime` object:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string month = now.ToString("MMMM",CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String month = 
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(
    DateTime.Now.Month);
```